Coverage Checks always 0%
In terminal, mvn verify is returning a test coverage of 0%
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.39 s -- in uk.ac.rhul.cs2800.Cw2ApplicationTests
[INFO] Running uk.ac.rhul.cs2800.model.StudentTest
[INFO] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 s -- in uk.ac.rhul.cs2800.model.StudentTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.12:report (report) @ CW2 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Users\readh\workspace\cs2800\cw2\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'CW2' with 7 classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.4.2:jar (default-jar) @ CW2 ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\readh\workspace\cs2800\cw2\target\CW2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.3.6:repackage (repackage) @ CW2 ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact C:\Users\readh\workspace\cs2800\cw2\target\CW2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF/.
[INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to C:\Users\readh\workspace\cs2800\cw2\target\CW2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.12:check (jacoco-check) @ CW2 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Users\readh\workspace\cs2800\cw2\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'CW2' with 7 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for package uk.ac.rhul.cs2800.repository: lines covered ratio is 0.0, but expected minimum is 0.9
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  30.333 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-10T17:50:51+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.12:check (jacoco-check) on project CW2: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Despite the junit tests covering over 90% in my IDE. The tests do run correctly so I'm not sure why this is happening.
Bear in mind that I did import both these tests and the classes they're running on from a previous project.
This is on mvn 3.9.9
I find this quite puzzling as mvn verify returned an accurate test coverage on my previous project. I'd assume there must be some problem with the version or my pom file?
Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>uk.ac.rhul.cs2800</groupId>
    <artifactId>CW2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CW2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <threshold>High</threshold>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.12</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Cw2Application*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-check</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>PACKAGE</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>LINE</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.9</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>checkstyle</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.6.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.12</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Cw2Application*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>


Have you checked the maven debug output to see if there is anything unusual? Is the jacoco.exec file recreated after a clean was done so that it's made sure it's not from a previous faulty build? What if you remove all exclusions from the jacoco config to see if you are excluding too much? Have you compared the command lines for test execution obtained from maven debug output and eclipse jacoco execution to spot any differences?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The error message tells about the package uk.ac.rhul.cs2800.repository we don't know about it.
